# WPF item selection from user control ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have created a user control with bind able ListView in it. I bind item source and selected item of this control and it works as expected when I use it once in a view. However when I try to reuse the same user control with different item source and selected item, item selection stops working - when I select item from one ListView item from another ListView gets unselected.

I bind my ListView like this:

```
<ListView
            x:Name="SelectionListView"
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=SelectionListControl, Path=Items}" 
            Background="Transparent" SelectedItem="{Binding  ElementName=SelectionListControl, Path=SelectedItem}">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="6"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:RadioButtonConfig Content="{Binding Text}" 
                         Template="{StaticResource RadioButtonConfig}" 
                         GroupName="DisplayPage"
                         IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"
                         IsConfigured="{Binding IsConfigured}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
```

I added my code to github [ListViewBinding project](https://github.com/aleksandraszagorskas/wpf-user-control-binding).

Edit:
ListView control code behind:

```
public partial class SelectionList : UserControl
    {
        public List<SelectionListItem> Items
        {
            get { return (List<SelectionListItem>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(List<SelectionListItem>), typeof(SelectionList), new PropertyMetadata(new List<SelectionListItem>()));


        public SelectionListItem SelectedItem
        {
            get { return (SelectionListItem)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(SelectionListItem), typeof(SelectionList), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new SelectionListItem(), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

        public SelectionList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

ListView Item model (SetProperty raises INotifyPropertyChanged PropertyChanged event):

```
public class SelectionListItem: ObservableObject
    {
        private string text;
        public string Text
        {
            get { return text; }
            set { SetProperty(ref text, value); }
        }

        private object valueObj;
        public object ValueObj
        {
            get { return valueObj; }
            set { valueObj = value; }
        }

        private bool isConfigured;
        public bool IsConfigured
        {
            get { return isConfigured; }
            set { SetProperty(ref isConfigured, value); }
        }
    }
```

I use my controls in MainWindow:

```
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <local:SelectionList
                x:Name="List1"
                Items="{Binding SelectableItems}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
            <TextBlock >
                <Run Text="Selected Item: "/>
                <Run Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Text, FallbackValue=SelectedItem}"/>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="Configured Item: "/>
                <Run Text="{Binding ConfiguredItem.Text, FallbackValue=ConfiguredItem}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>


        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <local:SelectionList
                x:Name="List2"
                Items="{Binding SelectableItems2}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem2}"/>
            <TextBlock >
                <Run Text="Selected Item: "/>
                <Run Text="{Binding SelectedItem2.Text, FallbackValue=SelectedItem}"/>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="Configured Item: "/>
                <Run Text="{Binding ConfiguredItem2.Text, FallbackValue=ConfiguredItem}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
```

With data binded from MainWindowViewModel:

```
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        #region list1
        private List<SelectionListItem> selectableItems = new List<SelectionListItem>();
        public List<SelectionListItem> SelectableItems
        {
            get { return selectableItems; }
            set
            {
                SelectedItem = value[0];
                SetProperty(ref selectableItems, value);
            }
        }

        private SelectionListItem selectedItem = new SelectionListItem { Text = "-", IsConfigured = false };
        public SelectionListItem SelectedItem
        {
            get { return selectedItem; }
            set { SetProperty(ref selectedItem, value); }
        }

        private SelectionListItem configuredItem = new SelectionListItem { Text = "-", IsConfigured = false };
        public SelectionListItem ConfiguredItem
        {
            get { return configuredItem; }
            set { SetProperty(ref configuredItem, value); }
        }

        private string valueText;
        public string ValueText
        {
            get { return valueText; }
            set { SetProperty(ref valueText, value); }
        }
        #endregion

        #region list1
        private List<SelectionListItem> selectableItems2 = new List<SelectionListItem>();
        public List<SelectionListItem> SelectableItems2
        {
            get { return selectableItems2; }
            set
            {
                SelectedItem2 = value[0];
                SetProperty(ref selectableItems2, value);
            }
        }

        private SelectionListItem selectedItem2 = new SelectionListItem { Text = "-", IsConfigured = false };
        public SelectionListItem SelectedItem2
        {
            get { return selectedItem2; }
            set { SetProperty(ref selectedItem2, value); }
        }

        private SelectionListItem configuredItem2 = new SelectionListItem { Text = "-", IsConfigured = false };
        public SelectionListItem ConfiguredItem2
        {
            get { return configuredItem2; }
            set { SetProperty(ref configuredItem2, value); }
        }

        private string valueText2;
        public string ValueText2
        {
            get { return valueText2; }
            set { SetProperty(ref valueText2, value); }
        }
        #endregion

    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show us how the code of the Items and SelectedItem properties.

Comment: Just a note. The default values of both the Items and SelectedItem properties are wrong. 1. You must not use a collection instance as default value for collection type dependency properties, because all instances of the owning class (i.e. your UserControl) would use the same collection (of course only as long as you do not set a property value other than the default). 2. There should not be a default selected item, especially not one that is not a member of the Items collection. Both default values should be null.

Comment: It is also unclear how you actually use two or more instances of your control. Do you bind them to different view models? Please show that also.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I edited my code, but that's probably not the problem in this case because defaults were not used. Also added additional info to the question.

Comment: As another note, duplicating view model properties and naming them by appending numbers looks totally odd. Create a child view model class with a single set of these properties and a parent view model with multiple child view model properties. Then bind like `Items="{Binding ChildVm2.SelectableItems}"`

Comment: Besides that, it would be safer to set `SelectedItem = value[0];` *after* `SetProperty(ref selectableItems, value);`